# Do you score for all smaller words within the long one in the same move in scrabble?

Tags: scrabble, scoring

If the word you play in scrabble contains several smaller words, do you score all of them, or just the longest? E.g. TRAIN as TRAIN+RAIN+IN, or just TRAIN? Cannot find it clarified in any rules...

Comment: This was the last time I played Scrabble, back in the 90's.  I was playing with my hypercompetitive grandmother, who was scoring Roman numerals this way.  When I pointed out I didn't think that was allowed she yelled at me that she'd been playing Scrabble since before I was born and so I couldn't tell her how to play.

Comment: just train as one word. however, if a player made "rain" an original word, collected points for that word, and added a t for "train" in the next move, THEN they would take credit for both.

Answer (score 13):

You only score each tile in a word once, where a word is the full sequence of letters added or modified in each column or row by your tile placement.

If you check the scoring example in the [official rules from Hasbro](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/rules) (click on the **Scoring** tab, then scroll to the bottom), it will show you how it works.

The first word in their example is **HORN** which gives a total score of 14. This is reached by adding 4 points for **H**, plus one point each for **O**, **R**, & **N** for a subtotal of 7. Because it is the first word played, it is given a double word score bonus for a total of 14.

Note that there is no additional score for the **O** and **R** making a subword of **OR**.

This can also be seen in the second word placed where **FARM** only scores a 9 - the subwords of **FAR** and **ARM** cannot be counted as part of the total score.

Note that a tile you place that creates or modifies words on 2 or more columns or rows can be counted multiple times (as in turn 4 of the linked example where adding **O** & **B** creates three words - **MOB**, **NOT**, & **BE**) but this is the only way that a tile can be scored multiple times on the same turn.

Comment: I would add that if a tile in the newly played word also forms a crossing word, that tile is scored for both the played word and the crossing word that was formed (occasionally, there will be multiple tiles doubly scored this way).  Word and letter bonuses are scored both ways only if the tile on the actual bonus square forms the crossing word, and of course bonuses (double letter, double word, etc.) are scored only on the turn in which tiles were played on them.

Comment: @ZeissIkon That would basically be rewriting the entire scoring rules. I will clarify my answer (later when I have the time to do so properly) to make it a little more accomodating of multi-word placement, but a lot of what you suggest is beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is that you play a single word, the fact that there are other words contained in that word doesn't matter, there is only one word you created, the full and final word. If you did gain points for subwords, then pluralizing a word would gain you effectively double the score. (-1 for the s)

There are very rare cases where a tile creates multiple full legal words, if the tiles you placed in the word you are creating modify an existing word in a legal way (most commonly pluralization) then and only then do you score for multiple words in a turn.

Comment: "*Rare*"! I don't think so. Roughly half the plays I make create at least two full legal words.